# Implement in appdelegate.m

Tags: objective-c

I add this in appdelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate () <DSRestClientDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) DSRestClient *restClient;
@end
```

But i want to Implement the    `DSRestClientDelegate`     methods, including     `restClientRegistered`    and    `restClient:registerFailedWithError`

Comment: CMD-click on `DSRestClientDelegate`to see the protocol declaration. Copy & paste the methods you need into the .m file.

Comment: You are probably better off creating a new class to be the delegate; there is no point in overloading the app delegate.

Comment: Let me translate what @trojanfor very politely put... Don't put it in the app delegate. That is not what it's for.